# Как скомпилировать APK без всплывающих окон?

Tags: android, apk, android-wear

У меня есть приложение на телефоне, которое конектится к часам и далее скачивает APK в браузере. Но так как APK не подписан Гуглом, вылазит окно с уведомлением, что данный файл может быть вредоносным, а часы по размерам маленькие — выбрать какое либо действие нельзя.

Как можно подписать APK так, чтобы не было данного окна?

[image: фото часов]

Comment: «скомпенсировать»?